# Use -match on JSON document to return different result if true

Tags: regex, json, powershell-2.0

What would be the best way of returning the first found value in `servers|addresses|addr` if `$json -Match` returns true, relative to the scope in which the specified `-Match` value is found?

For example, with the $json variable below:

```
If $json -Match "Aboubacar" returns true, then $result = "143.179.56.126"
If $json -Match "Tendaji" returns true, then $result = "113.55.212.113"
```

I'd like to accomplish this in Powershell version 2.

```
$json='
{
    "servers": [
        {
            "addresses": {
                "": [
                    {
                        "addr": "113.55.212.113",
                        "OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff",
                        "OS-EXT-IPS:type": "fixed",
                        "version": 4
                    }
                ]
            },
            "created": "2013-08-15T12:04:04Z",
            "flavor": {
                "id": "1",
                "links": [
                    {
                        "href": "http://openstack.example.com/flavors/1",
                        "rel": "bookmark"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "hostId": "117535ce0eda7ee02ebffe2c976173629385481ae3f2bded5e14a66b",
            "id": "ae114799-9164-48f5-a036-6ef9310acbc4",
            "image": {
                "id": "70a599e0-31e7-49b7-b260-868f441e862b",
                "links": [
                    {
                        "href": "http://openstack.example.com/images/70a599e0-31e7-49b7-b260-868f441e862b",
                        "rel": "bookmark"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "key_name": null,
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "http://openstack.example.com/v2.1/servers/ae114799-9164-48f5-a036-6ef9310acbc4",
                    "rel": "self"
                },
                {
                    "href": "http://openstack.example.com/servers/ae114799-9164-48f5-a036-6ef9310acbc4",
                    "rel": "bookmark"
                }
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "My Server Name": "Tendaji"
            },
            "name": "Tendaji"
        },
        {
            "addresses": {
                "": [
                    {
                        "addr": "143.179.56.126",
                        "OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff",
                        "OS-EXT-IPS:type": "fixed",
                        "version": 4
                    }
                ]
            },
            "created": "2013-08-15T12:04:04Z",
            "flavor": {
                "id": "1",
                "links": [
                    {
                        "href": "http://openstack.example.com/flavors/1",
                        "rel": "bookmark"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "hostId": "117535ce0eda7ee02ebffe2c976173629385481ae3f2bded5e14a66b",
            "id": "ae114799-9164-48f5-a036-6ef9310acbc4",
            "image": {
                "id": "70a599e0-31e7-49b7-b260-868f441e862b",
                "links": [
                    {
                        "href": "http://openstack.example.com/images/70a599e0-31e7-49b7-b260-868f441e862b",
                        "rel": "bookmark"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "key_name": null,
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "http://openstack.example.com/v2.1/servers/ae114799-9164-48f5-a036-6ef9310acbc4",
                    "rel": "self"
                },
                {
                    "href": "http://openstack.example.com/servers/ae114799-9164-48f5-a036-6ef9310acbc4",
                    "rel": "bookmark"
                }
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "My Server Name": "Aboubacar"
            },
            "name": "Aboubacar"
        }
    ]
}'

$json -Match "Aboubacar"  # if true return true, then $result = "143.179.56.126" as seen in `servers|addresses|addr`
$json -Match "Tendaji" # true, then $result = "113.55.212.113" as seen in `servers|addresses|addr`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to convert the JSON string to an object and then use simple object selection function in PowerShell. However, this approach requires an non-blank property name under 'adresses'.

Something like so:

```
$json='
{
    "servers": [
        {
            "addresses": {
                "addr": [
                    {
                        "addr": "113.55.212.113",
                        "OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff",
                        "OS-EXT-IPS:type": "fixed",
                        "version": 4
                    }
                ]
            },
            "created": "2013-08-15T12:04:04Z",
            "flavor": {
                "id": "1",
                "links": [
                    {
                        "href": "http://openstack.example.com/flavors/1",
                        "rel": "bookmark"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "hostId": "117535ce0eda7ee02ebffe2c976173629385481ae3f2bded5e14a66b",
            "id": "ae114799-9164-48f5-a036-6ef9310acbc4",
            "image": {
                "id": "70a599e0-31e7-49b7-b260-868f441e862b",
                "links": [
                    {
                        "href": "http://openstack.example.com/images/70a599e0-31e7-49b7-b260-868f441e862b",
                        "rel": "bookmark"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "key_name": null,
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "http://openstack.example.com/v2.1/servers/ae114799-9164-48f5-a036-6ef9310acbc4",
                    "rel": "self"
                },
                {
                    "href": "http://openstack.example.com/servers/ae114799-9164-48f5-a036-6ef9310acbc4",
                    "rel": "bookmark"
                }
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "My Server Name": "Tendaji"
            },
            "name": "Tendaji"
        },
        {
            "addresses": {
                "addr": [
                    {
                        "addr": "143.179.56.126",
                        "OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff",
                        "OS-EXT-IPS:type": "fixed",
                        "version": 4
                    }
                ]
            },
            "created": "2013-08-15T12:04:04Z",
            "flavor": {
                "id": "1",
                "links": [
                    {
                        "href": "http://openstack.example.com/flavors/1",
                        "rel": "bookmark"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "hostId": "117535ce0eda7ee02ebffe2c976173629385481ae3f2bded5e14a66b",
            "id": "ae114799-9164-48f5-a036-6ef9310acbc4",
            "image": {
                "id": "70a599e0-31e7-49b7-b260-868f441e862b",
                "links": [
                    {
                        "href": "http://openstack.example.com/images/70a599e0-31e7-49b7-b260-868f441e862b",
                        "rel": "bookmark"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "key_name": null,
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "http://openstack.example.com/v2.1/servers/ae114799-9164-48f5-a036-6ef9310acbc4",
                    "rel": "self"
                },
                {
                    "href": "http://openstack.example.com/servers/ae114799-9164-48f5-a036-6ef9310acbc4",
                    "rel": "bookmark"
                }
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "My Server Name": "Aboubacar"
            },
            "name": "Aboubacar"
        }
    ]
}'

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web.Extensions")
$ser = New-Object System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
$jsonObj = $ser.DeserializeObject($json)

$jsonObj.servers | Where-Object {$_.name -EQ 'Tendaji'} | `
  select-object { $_.addresses.addr[0].addr }

$jsonObj.servers | Where-Object {$_.name -EQ 'Aboubacar'} | `
  select-object { $_.addresses.addr[0].addr }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! I'm using Powershell v2, so I don't have the ConvertFrom-Json option. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: You could try to use this Powershell v2 extension: https://powershelljson.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks! Can you please give me an example of how it would integrate with what you have put above?

Comment: I update the deserialization to bit to reflect the use of the JavaScript serializer included in .NET assembly System.Web.Extensions. You will need ASP.NET 3.5 installed to use this method.